# only show 1 object from array in mat-select angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am using the latest version of Angular JS.

The example I am using is from (creating groups of options):

```
https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples
```

In the example, the HTML code is:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Pokemon" [formControl]="pokemonControl">
    <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups" [label]="group.name"
                  [disabled]="group.disabled">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon.value">
        {{pokemon.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I am trying to only show the first element of the array within the drop down. I will be using this array of "pokemon" groups at different points in the page, but I want to only show 1 group for now.

I have tried:

```
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups[0]" [label]="group.name">
```

In order to access only the first element (Grass):

```
 pokemonGroups: PokemonGroup[] = [
    {
      name: 'Grass',
      pokemon: [
        {value: 'bulbasaur-0', viewValue: 'Bulbasaur'},
        {value: 'oddish-1', viewValue: 'Oddish'},
        {value: 'bellsprout-2', viewValue: 'Bellsprout'}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Water',
      pokemon: [
        {value: 'squirtle-3', viewValue: 'Squirtle'},
        {value: 'psyduck-4', viewValue: 'Psyduck'},
        {value: 'horsea-5', viewValue: 'Horsea'}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Fire',
      disabled: true,
      pokemon: [
        {value: 'charmander-6', viewValue: 'Charmander'},
        {value: 'vulpix-7', viewValue: 'Vulpix'},
        {value: 'flareon-8', viewValue: 'Flareon'}
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Psychic',
      pokemon: [
        {value: 'mew-9', viewValue: 'Mew'},
        {value: 'mewtwo-10', viewValue: 'Mewtwo'},
      ]
    }
  ];
```

The error I get:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'Peru'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.ngOnChanges
```

Extremely new to Angular. Would appreciate any help / support

Comment: typo in name grass object? Are you missing an open brace? and left hand value in 'pokemon ' array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the object back into an array by wrapping it in `[]`. Update your template to be:

```
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of [pokemonGroups[0]]" [label]="group.name">
```

Comment: So this works, but because it's creating another array, If I use [pokemonGroups[1]] and select options from the other drop down, those elements are not added to the array

Answer (score 2):

if you want to show only one group, y are you opting to use `*ngFor`?
you can directly use - 
`<mat-optgroup [label]="pokemonGroups[0].name">`

Comment: Tried this already, thank you for your advice, but this does not work

Comment: this should work, can you check again as its working for me

Comment: This is the error I get: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pokemon' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Comment: Where is `pokemon` in `pokemonGroups[0].name`?

Comment: @dataviews the error you posted is related to `<mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon.value">
        {{pokemon.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>` can you share how you using that.Did you change that or left it as is?

Comment: @AmitChigadani i think he dint change the inner `*ngFor`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `slice` function on array to exclude all the items except first

```
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups.slice(pokemonGroups.length-1)" [label]="group.name">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Amit Chigadani solution just check before slicing data array.

```
   <div *ngFor="let group of (pokemonGroups? pokemonGroups.slice(0,1): [])" >
```